# Ubuntu Update Failed; how do I fix packages with broken triggers?

Tags: ubuntu, updates

I recently did an update on Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS x86_64, and on one machine accidentally closed the update dialog when it had an embedded terminal prompt asking [y/N].  This caused post-install triggers to break on the packages not yet installed.  Opening Synaptic doesn't fix the problem, and it mentions dpkg...

```
$ sudo dpkg --configure -a
Setting up linux-image-3.2.0-36-generic-pae (3.2.0-36.57) ...
Running depmod.
update-initramfs: deferring update (hook will be called later)
Examining /etc/kernel/postinst.d.
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 3.2.0-36-generic-pae /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-36-generic-pae
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-36-generic-pae
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/pm-utils 3.2.0-36-generic-pae /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-36-generic-pae
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/update-notifier 3.2.0-36-generic-pae /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-36-generic-pae
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub 3.2.0-36-generic-pae /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-36-generic-pae
debconf: DbDriver "config": /var/cache/debconf/config.dat is locked by another process: Resource temporarily unavailable
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub exited with return code 1
Failed to process /etc/kernel/postinst.d at /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-3.2.0-36-generic-pae.postinst line 1010.
dpkg: error processing linux-image-3.2.0-36-generic-pae (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-image-generic-pae:
 linux-image-generic-pae depends on linux-image-3.2.0-36-generic-pae; however:
  Package linux-image-3.2.0-36-generic-pae is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing linux-image-generic-pae (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-image:
 linux-image depends on linux-image-generic-pae (= 3.2.0.36.43); however:
  Package linux-image-generic-pae is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing linux-image (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-generic-pae:
 linux-generic-pae depends on linux-image-generic-pae (= 3.2.0.36.43); however:
  Package linux-image-generic-pae is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing linux-generic-pae (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux:
 linux depends on linux-image (= 3.2.0.36.43); however:
  Package linux-image is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing linux (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-3.2.0-36-generic-pae
 linux-image-generic-pae
 linux-image
 linux-generic-pae
 linux
$
```

How do I rollback the update and reapply it, or just force reinstallation of the broken ones?

Comment: This is [off-topic for Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions). I'm glad you were able to find a solution; if you decide you need more answers, you might want to ask about this on [Ask Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com), [Unix.SE](http://unix.stackexchange.com), or [Super User](http://superuser.com) (but search for it there first!).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wow, first downvote. Thanks.  Well I'll answer my own question.  This isn't the minimalistic or perfect solution, but when I subsequently installed another package, this caused the triggers to run again, and that fixed the problem.

sudo apt-get install git

(Git has nothing to do with it, I just needed it, and the package system fixed itself!)